# How would featuring R2-D2 alienate the New Republic Government?

Tags: star-wars, droids

According to the [Wookieepedia article on the R2-Series astromech droid](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/R2-series_astromech_droid):

> Ever since the droid came to the public's attention shortly after the
>   destruction of the first Death Star, despite having played a major
>   part in many previous events, sales showed their highest increase
>   since the launch of the series. IA resisted the urge to feature
>   Artoo-Detoo's heroics in its HoloNet advertisements released after the
>   fall of the Galactic Empire for fear of alienating New Republic
>   leaders.

How would featuring the heroics of the droid, which feels like the heroics of the Rebel Alliance, have alienated the New Republic's leaders?

Comment: Would YOU want to expose the whole band of miscreants (who are now your major contract buyer) as a bunch of bumbling nitwits who had to repeatedly be saved by an astromech droid? :)

Comment: @DVK, fair point, but I don't see how revealing that those R2 units helped in the Battle of Yavin could have hurt? Especially after Alderann and GIANT DEATH BALL OF DEATH. They wouldn't need to be like Porkins turned on too much gravity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This does not seem to have too much support in canon. As noted in the "Talk" section for that Wookieepedia page:

> **Alienating NR leaders?**
>
> > "IA resisted the urge to feature Artoo-Detoo's heroics 
> >             in its HoloNet advertisements released after the fall 
> >             of the Galactic Empire for fear of alienating New Republic leaders."

Where is that sourced? I want to know more about that.

In other words, this sounds like someone made the "fact" up and posted to the Wikia with no canon cites or references.

There is no mention of the fact in [Industrial Automaton](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Industrial_Automaton) Wikia page either.

Comment: I noticed this as well. I was a bit daunted at searching through ALL the sources listed in the article though, though I suppose that's on me to do my due dilligence.

Answer (score 1):

While the general public may have embraced the handy (handless) unit, (*I would suppose*) endorsing sentient spydroids would be bad for government business on several levels. Advertising the fact that R2D2 was capable of toppling an empire would be a political nightmare. They wouldn't be accepted with open arms. No matter how useful R2 units would be when they weren't spying on them, no politicaly conscious New Republic leader, evil or otherwise, would want their dirty laundry exposed for the galaxy to see, nor would they wish to compromise their data systems by utilizing what amounts to a rogue spydroid. Quietly selling them without fanfare would be a much wiser course of action.